# ng-select becomes unresponsive when binding to Array.filter()

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngselect

When binding an `ng-select` component to the result of an `Array.filter()`, selecting an option from the dropdown causes the page to become unresponsive.

Is there a correct way to bind to a filtered array of items?

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-array-filter-issue)

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

interface IListItem {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
<ng-select
  [items]="items"
  bindLabel="name"
  placeholder="Select item..."
  [(ngModel)]="selectedItem">
</ng-select>`
})
export class AppComponent  {

  private readonly _items: IListItem[] = [
    { id: 1, name: "One" },
    { id: 2, name: "Two" },
    { id: 3, name: "Three" },
    { id: 4, name: "Four" },
    { id: 5, name: "Five" },
    { id: 6, name: "Six" },
    { id: 7, name: "Seven" },
    { id: 8, name: "Eight" },
    { id: 9, name: "Nine" },
    { id: 10, name: "Ten" }
  ];

  get items(): IListItem[] {
    return this._items.filter(i => i.id % 2 === 0);
  }

  selectedItem: IListItem;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use function with ng-select, it gets called for each time which makes your ui unresponsive. Instead assign the filtered results to a variable,

```
filteredItems  =   this._items.filter(i => i.id % 2 === 0);
```

**[`STACKBLITZ DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-array-filter-issue-u2xwtm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Ideally I'd like to bind to the function as in my use case it's dynamic given the state of a service, however this does indeed work. I will refactor the service to recalculate the filter on state change and store results in a property. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this, a pipe appended to the items of the ng select,
if the filtered list is the same it will return the reference to the filtered list so that ng select wont keep running change detection returning a new list each time

```
externalLookupListFilter = (item) =>tem.id % 2 ===0
<ng-select #dropdown

[items]="lookupList | externalFilter: externalLookupListFilter"

</ng-select>

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'externalFilter'})
export class ExternalFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    
    
    private filteredList: Array<any> = undefined;
    transform(list: Array<any>, filterFunction: (item) => boolean, idProperty: string = 'id') {
        
        if (!filterFunction || !list) {
            return list;
        }
        
        const newList = list.filter(filterFunction);
        if(!this.arrayEquals(newList, this.filteredList, idProperty)) {
            this.filteredList = newList;
        }
        
        return this.filteredList;
    }
    
    private arrayEquals(a, b, idProperty) {
        return Array.isArray(a) &&
            Array.isArray(b) &&
            a.length === b.length &&
            (!idProperty ?
                a.every((val, index) => val === b[index]) // if no idproperty compare array as primitive values
                : a.every((val, index) => val[idProperty] === b[index][idProperty])); // if idproperty compare the idProperty of each object in arrays
    }
}
```